# CSS calc() behaviour in CSS variables

Tags: css, css-variables

I'm curious to the behaviour of using calc() in setting a CSS variable.

Example:

```
#test {
    --halfWidth: calc(100% / 2);
}
```

Now, if the `#test` element, say a `div`, was 500px wide, I would like the `--halfWidth` variable to be set to 250px.

But, as far as I can tell the `var(--halfWidth)` code used elsewhere simply drops in the `calc(100% / 2)` string instead of `250px`. Which means that I can't use the calculation of say element A and use it in element B later on, since it would simply set for example `width: var(--halfWidth);` as half the width of element B instead of half the width of element A, where the variable was defined.

I've scoured the web trying to find any documentation on the behaviour of this, but I have so far drawn a blank.

Ideally, setting a CSS variable using calc should be available in two variants:

1. One variant working just like this example, simply dropping in the string as-is, bar any in-string variable replacements.
2. A second variant where calc() would yield the result of the calculation instead of simply replacing the string.

How to achieve this? I'd rather leave the actual implementation to people suited to it, but one possibility would be an `eval()` kind of thing; like `eval(calc(100% / 2))` would give the result `250px`.

Anyway, if anyone have any real documentation on this behaviour or a solution to how to get the example above to yield the result instead, I'm all ears!

*Edit: Just FYI, I have read the specs at https://drafts.csswg.org/css-variables/*

Comment: Side note: Why not using LESS or SASS for such tasks?

Comment: I agree with @Justinas , SASS is more natural for this..

Comment: Have you looked at section 2.2 of the spec in particular?

Comment: @Justinas & Dhaval - of course I know about those options, but this is for research purposes, and besides; neither LESS or SASS can know about stuff like what I have in mind at run-time. Although very powerful, preprocessors can't mix units at runtime like CSS calc() can, for example.

Comment: @BoltClock - yeah, but it's rather ambigious I think; "Custom properties are left almost entirely unevaluated"... Almost entirely? :)

Anyhow, I was mostly wondering if there was a workaround.

Comment: Come to think of it, CSS variables would be enormously powerful if the spec could add some basic arithmetic functions. An `eval` function as mentioned above to get the result of a calc(), and `toNumber`, `floor`, `ceil` and `round`. You could for a given element get a variable that contained the number of columns available for a certain specified sub-element width (grids may solve this anyway, when usable) by doing something like `--variable: floor(toNumber(calc(100% / <sub-element width>)))`. Say the element this applies to is 1000px wide, sub-element is 300px, --variable would be 3.

Comment: And to fend off the negative comments right away; yes, I know CSS is primarily a presentational thing, and that the above can be achieved with javascript. Either way, CSS is already treading on the edge of programming with things like calc(), transitions and keyframes and the like, so...

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of a tough question to answer cause the answer will not be:

> Do it like this...then it will work

The problem you are facing is the normal behavior of CSS. It cascades the styles. If what you are trying to achieve would work it would get real messy after a short amount of time.

I mean how cool is it that you can define a variable like this

```
#test {
    --halfWidth: calc(100% / 2);
}
```

where `var(--halfWidth)` should always be `calc(100% / 2)`. Did you note that it will always be half the width of the parent element?

Imagine how strange it would be if a programmer in a few months reads your code and has box with a width of `1000px` set with `--halfWidth` and now it is `250px` wide ... I would think the internet is broken :) It should just be `500px` wide.

To achieve what you want, you could/should define different `var`s defining the widths of the parent elements. And split it down to the children.

Comment: Indeed it has a very real possibility of confusing the hell out of people, but that's kind of why I wanted to ask the question here - to make sure I didn't miss something very obvious. Because if **I** can think that the CSS variable is assigned the _value_ of the calculation, others can too. And that in itself is confusing. Mostly, I'd like to see this stated clearly somewhere in the spec, not in such an ambigious phrasing as in section 2.2.

Answer (score 0):

One approach to this is to dynamically add a line to the **CSS Object Model** (**CSSOM**) which explicitly declares the `width` of the `.halfwidth` class.

This `width` will then apply to all divs with the `.halfwidth` class.

In the example below, I have, additionally, made `.element-a` horizontally resizable, so that you can see more clearly that as you change the `width` of `.element-a`, the `width` of *both* `.halfwidth` divs changes proportionately, including the `.halfwidth` div which is a child of `.element-b`.

**Working Example:**

```js
let myStylesheet = document.styleSheets[0];
const elementA = document.getElementsByClassName('element-a')[0];
let elementAWidth = window.getComputedStyle(elementA).getPropertyValue('width');

const calculateHalfWidth = (elementAWidth) => {

  myStylesheet.insertRule('.halfWidth { width: ' + (parseInt(elementAWidth) / 2) + 'px; }', myStylesheet.cssRules.length);
}

calculateHalfWidth(elementAWidth);

// ================================================================================
// THE SCRIPT BELOW USES A ResizeObserver TO WATCH THE RESIZABLE .element-a DIV
// ================================================================================

const elementAObserver = new ResizeObserver(entries => {
  for (let entry of entries) {
    if (entry.contentRect.width !== elementAWidth) {
      calculateHalfWidth(entry.contentRect.width);
    }
  }
});

elementAObserver.observe(elementA);
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

div.element {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 12px 3px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

div.element h2 {
  font-size: 18px;
}

div.element-a {
  resize: horizontal;
  overflow: auto;
}

div.element-b {
  width: 300px;
}


div.halfWidth {
  height: 40px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px dashed rgb(255, 0, 0);
}

div.halfWidth h2 {
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<div class="element element-a">
<h2>Element A</h2>
  
  <div class="halfWidth">
    <h2>halfWidth</h2>
  </div>
  
</div>

<div class="element element-b">
  <h2>Element B</h2>
  
  <div class="halfWidth">
    <h2>halfWidth</h2>
  </div>
  
</div>
```