# Combine CSS-variables and calc()

Tags: css, css-variables, css-calc

I want to combine CSS-variables and calc(), but like mentioned in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37385418/css-calc-behaviour-in-css-variables) before (that has no precise answer) there seems to be a problem if you do things like the follwing:

```
--a: 1;
--b: 2; 
--result: calc(var(--a) + var(--b));
```

The output for this example should be 3 of course, but if you use var(--result) it just has the value var(calc(1 + 2)).

**Note:** I don't want to use a preprocessor (like sess or lass), just native CSS.

**So my question is:** Can you somehow force the calc()-function to be executed before its result is used in var(--result)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6):

CSS is not C++, so these aren't instructions to be exucted sequentially, these are CSS declaration.

`--result` is equal to `calc(var(--a) + var(--b))` and only when you will use the variable the browser will do the final calculation because `--a` and `--b` may change depending on the element so saying that `--result` should be equal to `3` is false.

Here is an example to illustrate this:

```css
.box {
  --a: 1;
  --b: 2;
  --result: calc(var(--a) + var(--b));
  height: calc(var(--result) * 10px);
  border: 1px solid;
}

.alt {
  --a: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
 my height is equal to 30px because result is evaluated to 3 (1+2)
</div>

<div class="box alt">
 my height is equal to 40px because result is evaluated to 4 (2+2)
</div>
```